# How do I adjust this for single/multithreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that basically has two methods the first one takes a String (name of a file) and a thread:

```
public static void readFile(String s, Thread t){
    Runnable read = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          //SOME CODE



}
        t = new Thread(read);
    t.start();

}
```

The second method is a main method that asks the user for input and then uses that input to set a few things (like if the number of threads is just one or if it is equal to the number of objects in a list).

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  //SOME CODE

  for(Object x: ListOfObjects){
  //t1 is the same thread each time if one thread requested, otherwise t1 is a different thread each time
  readFromFile(textFileString, t1);
  //SOME CODE
}
```

If the user were to request 5 threads (for 5 items in a list), how could the above be modified for that? Currently, my main method has a loop (for the number of items in the list) and then the first method is called for each iteration in the loop.  Is there a way to take the number of threads requested by the user, and initiate/start them in the first method all at once instead of one at a time and calling the method?

Comment: try replacing "adjust **this**" in your title with something more descriptive.

Comment: isn't the `Thread t` parameter redundant in the first method? You are overriding it before using it. Or is it assigned somewhere in `SOME CODE`?

Comment: And yes, now that I look at it, the parameter is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the Runnable interface.  I tried
this and it seems to work:

```
class StringThread implements Runnable
{
    private String str;
    private int num;

    StringThread(String s, int n)
    {
        str  = new String (s);
        num =n; 
    }

    public void run ( )
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=num; i++)
            System.out.print ("THREAD NAMED: " + str+"  I IS: " +
                                               i + "\n"); 
    }
}

//IN the main program:

StringThread t1 = new StringThread ("THR-1",100);
new Thread(t1). start ( );    
StringThread t2 = new StringThread ("THR-2",200);
new Thread(t2). start ( );
```

Comment: There's no reason to extend `Thread` there (there **very** rarely is).

Comment: What's the `new String (s)` supposed to do?

Comment: The statement str = new String (s) in the constructor is just to set the String name of the class to the input string so that the thread can potentially be referenced by this String